# How to map multiple beans in Mybatis?

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I have two beans (1) **CarBean** and (2) **WheelBean**  as follow

```
public class CarBean implements Serializable {
  private Long carId;
  private List<WheelBean> wheels;
}
```

I have two tables for car and wheel. I would like to query data from **car** table and use *left-join* to **wheel** table. I would like to use as follow

```
  <select id='getCarById' parameterType='Long' resultType='mypackage.CarBean'>
    SELECT
     C.*,W.*
     FROM CAR C
     LEFT JOIN WHEEL W
     ON C.CAR_ID = W.CAR_ID
     WHERE CAR_ID = #{carId}
  </select>
```

But this way , I can't get datas from wheel table because there has no matching datas for wheel information. So , now I am using as *extends* **CarBean** to **WheelBean** and at my datasource xml is

```
  <select id='getCarById' parameterType='Long' resultType='mypackage.WheelBean'>
    SELECT
     C.*,W.*
     FROM CAR C
     LEFT JOIN WHEEL W
     ON C.CAR_ID = W.CAR_ID
     WHERE CAR_ID = #{carId}
  </select>
```

This way , I can get both **CarBean** and **WheelBean** datas. My problem is that *".. has there any way to get both carBean and wheelBean datas without extending carBean to wheelBean ?"*

I think in normal , **WheelBean** should extends **CarBean** rather than **CarBean** from. Am I right ? At my service layer , **WheelBean** List is composite in **CarBean**. How would I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map as many as you want but `MyBatis` will provide query result through a method `queryForObject` or `queryForList` or some other...

**No method in the world can return two value.**
so only way is to bind them in one class.

Now as you don't want `extending carBean to wheelBean` so you can give it a try

- Create another class for result containing purpose which will contains both carBean  and wheelBean as property
- then make result map like

  `<resultMap class="mypackage.YourNewClass" id="mapId">`
   `<result property="carBean.pro1" column="" />`
  `<result property="carBean.pro2" column="" />`
  `......`
  `<result property="wheelBean.pro1" column="" />`
  `<result property="wheelBean.pro2" column="" />`
- then show this result map to select query

  `<select id="getCarById" resultMap="mapId"    parameterClass="Long">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! but I didn't mean one method to return two values . My actual problem is  I don't want to use **CarBean** to extends **WheelBean**. So you said *...only way is to bind them in one class* . how ?  how to bind and how to map without extends ?

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer. I just only use auto mapping. Mapping as like `<result property="carBean.pro2" column="" />` fix my problem. Thanks sir .

Comment: Welcome. I am really glad to know that it helped.